# Magento show best Teirprice in category list

Tags: arrays, magento, magento-1.7

having an issue displaying the best tier price in Magento 1.7

The code below works perfectly well but it's only getting the first array price, so it's not the best possible multi buy tier price.

```
<?php
                    /* get the data */


                    $my_tier_rocks = $this->getTierPrices();
                    if (!empty($my_tier_rocks)){
                        $my_tier_rocks = $this->getTierPrices();

                            // Notice you may not be using formated_price_incl_tax but other field.
                            $my_tier_rocks = $my_tier_rocks[0]['formated_price_incl_tax'];

                            $_savingPercent = round((($my_tier_rocks-$_finalPrice)/$my_tier_rocks)*100,1);

                    ?>
                    <? /* let's print the data */ ?>
                    <? /* Use the HTML you want just notice the $my_tier_rocks var */ ?>
                    <span class="cat_multibuyprice">                     
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Multi Buy Price:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price"><?=$my_tier_rocks?></span>               
                    </span>

                    <?php $_savingAmount = $_regularPrice-$_finalPrice; ?>

                    <? } /*end showing tier prices */ ?>
```

Any help to show the best tier price would be great,

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, silly me.

I simply used end($array); to get the last and best price of the array.

```
<?php
                    /* get the data */


                    $my_tier_rocks = $this->getTierPrices();
                    if (!empty($my_tier_rocks)){
                        $my_tier_rocks = $this->getTierPrices();

                            // Notice you may not be using formated_price_incl_tax but other field.
                              $my_tier_best_price = end($my_tier_rocks);

                                    $my_tier_rocks = $my_tier_best_price['formated_price_incl_tax'];

                                $_savingPercent = round((($my_tier_rocks-$_finalPrice)/$my_tier_rocks)*100,1);

                    ?>
                    <? /* let's print the data */ ?>
                    <? /* Use the HTML you want just notice the $my_tier_rocks var */ ?>
                    <span class="cat_multibuyprice">                     
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Multi Buy Price:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price"><?=$my_tier_rocks?></span>               
                    </span>

                    <?php $_savingAmount = $_regularPrice-$_finalPrice; ?>

                    <? } /*end showing tier prices */ ?>
```